# Parralel payments with Paypal - who is gonna to pay fee?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using Paypal Parralel payments.
I wonder how to set who have to pay paypal fee.

How is it by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify who pays these fees. Fee payment configurations include:

- Sender Pays the Fee
- Receiver Pays the Fee in a Parallel Payment

(Basically the sender OR each individual receiver)

For more information please look at the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)